# Requests with While True

Tags: python, while-loop, python-requests, telegram

I got a nice working sample of requests which works only in While True func and Threading when I get current exchange rate. When I remove While True every time this function calls I see the only one and only the first request result without any updating even if I call this function again

Could you please help me why does this happen and how to avoid using While True?

I know it looks unclear, just take a look at both samples.

While True requests:

```
def get_currency():
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(30)
            #here I get the currency
            else:
                pass
            print(result)

def MyBot():
    While True:
          print(result)
          # here's my tg bot gets 'result' variable and it updates every 30 seconds

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Thread(target=get_currency)
    t2 = Thread(target=MyBot)
    t1.daemon = True
    t2.daemon = True
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    while True:
        pass
```

This function works perfect but for some reasons I have to avoid using While True construction and when I try to just simply removing it this function works but the currency never get updated - it shows to me the first result every 30 seconds

```
result = 0
def get_currency():
    global result 
    try:
        time.sleep(30)
        #here I get the currency and put it in 'result' variable
        else:
            pass
        print(result)

def MyBot():
    while True:
         print(result)
         # here's my tg bot gets 'result' variable and it DOES NOT UPDATE every 30 seconds. It shows me the first result without getting any updates of this variable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Thread(target=get_currency)
    t2 = Thread(target=MyBot)
    t1.daemon = True
    t2.daemon = True
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    while True:
        pass
```

Im so sorry that my question probably sounds confusing but I'll be glad to try to clarify it

Comment: so MyBot() is using get_currenct(), to receive a result, wich it prints on telegram?
EDIT:

I think the main problem here is that the threads doesnt share the same local variable in the stack. Have you tried other approach to share the result between the threads?

Answer (score 0):

I see a difference in the first code and the second code, that in the first code, u dont have result assigned as a global variable. Have you tried the first code with result assigned as global? it seems correct to me.